# php + http_post_data

Tags: php

Is there a way to check if this is installed?
Maybe something in phpinfo()?

I'm doing the call below and I don't get any reply at all. The page just ends when it gets to it.

```
        $postdata = array(
            'validation' => '1'
        );


        $response = http_post_data('../ajax/index_ajax_general.php', $postdata);
        print $response;
```

Comment: Where exactly is the script stopping? There aren't any errors or warnings showing? You can try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of your script to make sure errors and warnings are outputted. Also, there might be an `error_log` file in your script directory that could have any errors thrown by your script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
if (extension_loaded('pecl_http') == false) {
    // do not have extension
}

// or

if (function_exists('http_post_data') == false) {
    // function not available
}
```

Given that function is a PECL extension, you will probably find most PHP installations do not have these functions available.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the documentation this function requires at least PHP v5.0:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.requirements.php

If you don't get an error like "undefined function ..." the function is available and something with your code is wrong...